# How to update code on multiple servers at once

Tags: python, server

I'm relatively new to working with server instances so please excuse my limited knowledge. I have a python script that I run for 5 different people. Each person who I run it for, has a slightly different file (Ie: some names in the script are changed to work with their branding and name), and right now when I get a new client, I have to copy the script, and change each part that needs to be changed by hand, and then run that in my server (I'm running all 5 scripts on the same server). If I make any changes to my codebase, I need to change the script for each of my clients, go to the server and swap out the old versions by hands.

I'm expecting to have this grow to a couple hundred clients so this is just not a feasible method. Are there any products or methods I can use to fix this product, or atleast make it easier to update all the files at once?

Comment: It would be way better if you could parameterize your script so that there could be just one, or maybe a few at most, and the parameters could describe the different behaviors for each client.  You could even pass in code as parameter values if necessary.  Is this really not possible?  One way or the other, you obviously have to automate not just the deployment, I'd think, but the maintenance of the scripts themselves.  You shouldn't need to manually apply the same change to a bunch of script files.

Comment: You can use ci/cd process where you keep the code same everywhere and in deployment change the data according to the user (considering you are providing same functionlity to all and with minor changes)

Comment: Would be a simple job for Ansible.

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the specifics of the script it's really hard to say, but here are a couple of solutions that might work:

1. Pass the values that change as arguments to the script - Use something like `argparse` to capture the arguments into variables
2. Modify the script to run on a list of arguments - This is pretty easy to do - literally just add a for-loop around your entire script and iterate over the values for each of your clients.